# C# - Socket cannot bind on new ip after changing it by control panel

Tags: c#, sockets, ip, bind

I discovered some problems by calling the "`Bind(IPEndPoint)`" method on a socket instance as soon as an adapter changes it's ip address.

Questions:

- Why is the new ip not available for about the first 4 seconds after changing it?
- If it is expected to behave like this, how to avoid to provocate exceptions while waiting to get the ip available finally?
- Do i have to change the socket binding ip in order to receive incoming connections after network adapter gets a new ip?

For reproduction, I appended the code on bottom. Run it, and while running it, change the ip address of the one network adapter displayed in the first output line.

Short description:

I register on "`NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged`". Now I change my IP address using windows, which fires the `NetworkAddressChanged` event. There, the socket listening on the old local endpoint ip, will be disposed and replaced by a new socket listening on the new local endpoint ip. This seems to work, but with a little delay around 4 seconds. Within those 4 seconds, the method "`Bind`" throws an `SocketException` with `SocketErrorCode = AddressNotAvailable.` What is going wrong there?

Simplified Code:

```
class Program {
    private static Socket socket;
    private static IPEndPoint localEP;
    private static NetworkInterface niEth;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 12345);
        NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged;
        RefreshNetworkInterfaceIP();
        while (true) Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    private static void NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        RefreshNetworkInterfaceIP();
    }
    private static void RefreshNetworkInterfaceIP() {
        niEth = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(IsUsableInterface);
        Console.WriteLine("Using \"{0}\" as interface!", niEth.Name);
        IPAddress newIP = niEth.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).Address;
        // It looks like the new IPAddress is properly set, but Bind still refuses to use this ip...
        if (!localEP.Address.Equals(newIP)) {
            UnbindSocket();
            localEP.Address = newIP;
            BindSocket();
        }
    }
    private static bool IsUsableInterface(NetworkInterface ni) {
        return ni != null
            && ni.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
            && (
                ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet
                || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
            && ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Any(x => x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    }
    private static void BindSocket() {
        if (socket != null) UnbindSocket();
        socket = new Socket(localEP.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        do { // This is the waiting workaround.
            try { socket.Bind(localEP); } catch (SocketException e) {
                if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.AddressNotAvailable) {
                    Console.WriteLine("The new IP is not ready, waiting a sec...");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        } while (!socket.IsBound);
        socket.Listen(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Socket now listens on: {0}", socket.LocalEndPoint);
    }
    private static void UnbindSocket() {
        if (socket == null) return;
        try { socket.Dispose(); } catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
        socket = null;
    }
}
```

This code snippet actually works fine, and thanks to "`CurrPorts`", socket is really binding and listening to new IP. Even after a call to GC after "`socket = null`", same behavior.

Note: The surrounding mechanism of this code snippet can now successfully handle following situations:

- Network adapters: Reaction on adding/removing adapters of any kind, even the invisible ones (isatap, ...)
- WiFi: On/Off by Airplane-Mode, discrete switch and software/driver activation/deactivation/reset
- RJ45: Cable out/in, software/driver activation/deactivation/reset

In those cases, the mechanism around that socket knows what it is doing, it is even waiting on isatab and tap-adapters to get their addresses to use them simultaneously.

The only thing is: Windows Network Discovery, triggered by IP address change (tested IPv4 only), which shows up the new ip in "`NetworkInterface`" but refuses to use it. If IPv6 struggles the same way IPv4 does, I have to find a proper solution for 2 problems except the one I thought it was the only one :)

I am still working forward to get my Project done (some kind of "`Network Service Abstraction Layer`" for high reliability), but those kind of problems are really nasty to solve and work with...

I would be very happy if someone can point me to the right direction to either wait precisely for binding the socket or to avoid exceptions while trying to bind to that new ip.

Thanks in advance, GK

Comment: Are you a hacker?  Why would anybody change an IP address dynamically?

Comment: A hacker? Yes, I use a keyboard ~100k times per day :-) But actually, this is an attempt to program a high responsive, self maintaining network servicing system, that does not need a reboot each time something changes...

Comment: waiting only 4 seconds for a new IP isn't bad.  Windows operate off of timers and updating any object may take time for events to occur and data to get updated.  I suspect the changing of the IP requires an ARP to occur to notify other computers of the new IP and time is required to the ARP response to occur and the ARP table to get updated.  then for Group Policy to take effect the Group Server (DCHP) must process an update.

Comment: I recognised that windows is trying to "identify network" within this time where the code isn't able to bind to the new IP. This behavior occurs on dhcp as well as automatic (169.x.x.x) and manual IP addresses.

Comment: @GökhanKarabulut, did you find a solution to the 4 second delay problem? I am facing the exact same situation. When the IPv4 address of my network adapter changes, I need to wait 4 seconds before I can bind a socket to the network adapter. If I don't, I get an exception. Is there a function that I can call that notifies me when the IPv4 address of the network adapter has finished updating? Thank you!